# How to open a file in another app in API 24 and above - andorid

Tags: java, android

i have a file's path and i want the device to open the file with another app

```
 public static void openUrl(Context context, String path) {
    Uri uriForFile;
    if  (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
        uriForFile = GenericFileProvider.getUriForFile(context,"xyz.provider",new File(path));
    }else{
        uriForFile = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
    }
    MimeTypeMap myMime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    String mimeType = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExt(path).substring(1));
    newIntent.setDataAndType(uriForFile, mimeType);
    newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    try {
        context.startActivity(newIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.msg_noHandlerForThisTypeOfFile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

the above code works well on api 23 and lower

but in android 7 when i want to open a mp3 file for example it Toast "the player doesn't support this type of audio file"

or when i open a image it open a blank page with gallery app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

with:

```
newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Right now, the third-party app has no rights to your `GenericFileProvider` content.